# What is meant by proper declaration of read resolve method in the Effective Java book?

Tags: java, serialization, effective-java

From the Serialization chapter of Effective Java:

> If the class of an object being deserialized defines a readResolve
>   method with the proper declaration, this method is invoked on the
>   newly created object after it is deserialized.

The example provided in Effective Java is the following and it seems like the `throws` part is missing from what the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) says is the correct format ie `ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException;`

```
 // readResolve for instance control - you can do better!
        private Object readResolve () {
            // Return the one true Elvis and let the garbage collector
            // take care of the Elvis impersonator.
            return INSTANCE;
        }
```

What is meant by *proper declaration* here? Will the class even compile if the declaration is not proper? I am finding the sentence a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the javadoc of [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> Classes that need to designate a replacement when an instance of it is
>   read from the stream should implement this special method with the
>   exact signature.
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object readResolve() throws
>   ObjectStreamException;

So `proper declaration` means the method must have the same declaration as above.

This behavior exists [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017819/438154)

> Serializable serves as a marker to the JRE/JVM, which may take
>   action(s) based on its presence.

But doesn't have any abstract methods declared of its own.

Comment: If you read the `ObjectInputStream` source code, it never checks whether the throws clause exists or not. So even though `throws ObjectStreamException` is officially "proper", it still works without it. It does though document that `ObjectStreamException` is the only checked exception it will accept without turning it into an `IOException` (with message `"unexpected exception type"` and the unexpected checked exception as its cause)

Answer (score 2):

Proper declaration means method must have this signature:

```
Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

During deserialization, after an object T was successfully deserialized, if object T contains a method readResolve() declared as above (via reflection, of course) it is automatically called.
Look [this tutorial](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html) or [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html)